# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core) on tests

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-test

we are using the new version of FlutterFire, but we have some issues when running our tests, we managed to initialise Firebase adding this:

```dart
setUp(() async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  });
```

But now we have this error message:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
  package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 159:7  MethodChannel._invokeMethod
```

The app runs well both on iOS and Android, we only have the issue when running the widget tests. We've tried with Flutter stable and dev channels.

Comment: Facing the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you are performing either unit or widget testing.
Just take a look at how the plugin itself [is being tested](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core/test/firebase_core_test.dart).

`class FakeFirebaseAppPlatform extends Fake implements FirebaseAppPlatform {}`

They just fake the object.

**Why**? because this plugin is implemented using method channels and while testing you don't have access to the native platform .Your only option is to mock or fake your interactions with Firebase either:

1. As the authors of the plugin are doing using Mockito
2. Mock the method channel as illustrated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028969/testing-flutter-code-that-uses-a-plugin-and-platform-channel) , (which is in my opinion more cumbersome, and best suited if you are developing a plugin yourself)

Comment: great answer just to add that flutter fire does mention this in their own docs https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/testing/testing/