# Testing platform channel in Flutter 2.8

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

There have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028969/testing-flutter-code-that-uses-a-plugin-and-platform-channel) about testing `MethodChannel`. After I upgrade Flutter to 2.8, it seams there has no method called `setMockMethodCallHandler` in channel.

Answer (score 0):

In the breaking changes [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/mock-platform-channels), it has mentions about [new method](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/mock-platform-channels#migration-guide):

```dart
// old code
myMethodChannel.setMockMethodCallHandler(...);
myMethodChannel.checkMockMethodCallHandler(...);
// new code
tester.binding.defaultBinaryMessenger.setMockMethodCallHandler(myMethodChannel, ...);
tester.binding.defaultBinaryMessenger.checkMockMessageHandler(myMethodChannel, ...);
```

By the way, Flutter team do [motions](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7474#issuecomment-558882182) they want to do more things in widgets test instead of driver test.

> We're moving away from flutter_driver in favour of extending flutter_test to work on devices.

Take [ImagePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) as example:

```dart
widgetTest('', (tester) async {
  const channel = MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/image_picker');
  tester.binding.defaultBinaryMessenger.setMockMethodCallHandler(
    channel,
    (MethodCall methodCall) => Future.value('some-image'),
  );
});
```